# How to open a external terminal from emacs

Tags: term

Brand new emacs user here.

I want to have the ability of opening a terminal with current file path from emacs, like what the `open terminal here` package does in sublime text 2.

By terminal, I mean a separate external terminal emulator running bash or zsh, like gnome-terminal, not the emulated shells inside emacs, like `M-x shell` `M-x eshell`, which I can't appreciate for now.

I googled but had nothing found... It seems that emacs guys really enjoy living in emacs.

Comment: Have you tried `M-x` `ansi-term`? It's much better than `shell`. I use it and it works really well. Or do you mean a new graphical terminal (like opening a `gnome-terminal`)?

Comment: @PythonNut I've just tried it, it even couldn't handle the tab completion... So I still prefer a new terminal window.
Ahhh, I've just tried `M-! gnome-terminal`, it works. I'm wondering why `M-! bash` couldn't do it.

Comment: @Ply_py I think you need to tell **terminal emulator** and **shell**. `bash` is a shell, `M-! bash` surely won't do what you want. Please find out what terminal emulator you're using first.

Comment: @kuanyui Ahh, I just searched these two words... and found the answers [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/111144/are-terminal-and-shell-the-same). Clearly I mixed up the notions of shell and terminal(emulator). Thanks, I'll edit the question.

Comment: shell and ansi-term definitely do handle tab completion, at least with bash. I use shell every day.

Comment: @Ply_py the one pitfall of `ansi-term` is the ease of which you can configure it to death. Try `ansi-term` in an `emacs -Q` session. It works pretty well, even for me with my crazy [shell config](https://github.com/PythonNut/zsh-config).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Another try that disowns the process so your terminal will survive even after emacs is killed.

```
(defun run-gnome-terminal-here ()
  (interactive "@")
  (shell-command (concat "konsole --workdir"
            (file-name-directory (or load-file-name buffer-file-name)) 
              " > /dev/null 2>&1 & disown") nil nil))
```

Comment: Is there a way to tie the spawned terminal to the lifetime of the emacs process?

Comment: This doesn't work (emacs freezes until the terminal exits) if your terminal generates any debug messages when loading.  To fix, swap the order of `2>&1` and `>/dev/null` (so that `>/dev/null` comes first).

Comment: When I try this, Emacs doesn't even let me call the function. After evaluation, the mini buffer says `gnome-terminal-here` but when entering `gnome-terminal-here`, it says `[No match]`.

Comment: @UTF-8 That's because the function wasn't declared as an interactive command. See my edit.

Answer (score 2):

What terminal emulator are you using? Take KDE's `Konsole` as example, just write a function:

```
(defun open-konsole ()
  (interactive)
  (call-process "konsole" nil 0 nil "--workdir" default-directory))
```

The args from 5st place are konsole's argument. See your prefered terminal simulator's man page.

`M-x open-konsole` will open a new konsole process and use current `default-directory` (`pwd` in ELisp) as working directory.

Comment: One can open new tab if konsole is already running with `(call-process "konsole" nil 0 nil "--new-tab" "--workdir" default-directory)`. Also `(call-process "wmctrl" nil 0 nil "-a" "\" – Konsole\"")` to activate its window.

Answer (score 2):

The other answers didn't work for me. This code does:

```
(defun open-gnome-terminal ()
  (interactive)
  (shell-command "gnome-terminal"))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the external package [terminal-here](https://github.com/davidshepherd7/terminal-here). This does only one thing, but does it well; exactly what you requested. And works for me on multiple OS.

Answer (score 1):

Building on terminal-here as proposed before, I created a small function that determines depending on the system and desktop environment the program to run. It can be useful if you like changing desktop, or keep your `.emacs` synchronized between several computers. Note that I didn't tested the windows/darwin/gnome/... shell code, only KDE is tested for now.

```
;; ##########################################################
;; ### Open terminal
;; ##########################################################

;; Define a function to recognize the desktop environment easily
;; You shouldn't need to touch this function
(defun get-desktop-environment ()
  (interactive)
  (let (
    ;; Create new variable with DE name
    (de_env (getenv "XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP"))
    ;; Make sure search is case insensitive
    (case-fold-search t))
    (cond ((eq system-type 'darwin)
       "darwin")
      ((memq system-type '(windows-nt ms-dos cygwin))
       "windows")
      ((string-match ".*kde.*" de_env)
       "kde")
      ((string-match ".*gnome.*" de_env)
       "gnome")
      ((string-match ".*unity.*" de_env)
       "unity")
      ((string-match ".*xfce.*" de_env)
       "xfce")
      ((string-match ".*lxde.*" de_env)
       "lxde")
      ((string-match ".*mate.*" de_env)
       "mate")
      ((string-match ".*cinnamon.*" de_env)
       "cinnamon")
      (t "unknown"))))

;; You can edit this function if you want to change the default command for a specific desktop
(defun get-terminal (path)
  (alist-get (get-desktop-environment)
         '(("darwin" . ("open" "-a" "Terminal.app" "."))
           ("windows" . ("cmd.exe" "/C" "start" "cmd.exe"))
           ("kde" . ("konsole" "--workdir" "."))
           ("gnome" . ("gnome-terminal" "--working-directory=."))
           ("xfce" . ("xfce4-terminal" "--working-directory=.")))
         '("x-terminal-emulator") nil 'equal))

(use-package terminal-here
  :ensure t
  :bind (("<f6>" . terminal-here-launch))
  :config
  (setq terminal-here-terminal-command #'get-terminal))
```

Answer (score 0):

Most of the time I use `shell-mode`. So I heavily use [shell-here](https://github.com/ieure/shell-here). But when I need external terminal. I use urxvt-client with tmux using this:

- Create file named 'term-here' in /usr/local/bin/ containing

```
urxvtc -e bash -c "tmux -q has-session && exec tmux attach-session -d || exec tmux new-session -n$USER -s$USER@$HOSTNAME"
```

- Create new function in emacs

```
(defun term-here ()
  (interactive)
  (start-process "" nil "term-here"))
```

- Bind to your favorite key

This will open urxvt-client (with tmux) in your current directory. I bind it in dired-mode-map.

```
(use-package dired
  :ensure nil
  :ensure-system-package urxvt
  :bind ((:map dired-mode-map
           ("," . term-here))))
```

I choose urxvt-client because it is fast and simple. Don't forget to run your urxvt-daemon at startup.

Answer (score 0):

This worked perfectly fine for me: `(delete-window  (async-shell-command "gnome-terminal"))`. Swap out your terminal command.